# Copy Each Line of a List into a Separate Text File

Tags: python

I have two lists of equal length. One contains the names of the files I would like to create while the other is a 2-d list that has data I would like to copy into a text file with a name from the list. I want each element from the 2D list to have its own separate text file. The example code is as follows:

Source Code:

```py
 example_data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    example_names = ['name1.txt', 'name2.txt', 'name3.txt']

    for name in example_names:
      for ele in example_data:
        with open(name, 'w') as f:
            f.writelines('0 ' + str(ele).replace('[',replace(']', '').replace(',', ''))
```

Current Output:

```
name1.txt,  
data within file: 0 7 8 9

name2.txt,  
data within file: 0 7 8 9

name3.txt,  
data within file: 0 7 8 9
```

Expected output:

```
name1.txt,  
data within file: 0 1 2 3

name2.txt,  
data within file: 0 4 5 6

name3.txt,  
data within file: 0 7 8 9
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post a picture of your code, instead, please post the code itself in your post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Logic

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to get both the element side by side and use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to convert `list` to `str` and as it's `list` of `int` you need to convert every individual element to `str` type.

### Solution

#### Source Code

```py
example_data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
example_names = ["name1.txt", "name2.txt", "name3.txt"]

for file_name, data in zip(example_names, example_data):
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write(f"0 {' '.join([str(x) for x in data])}")
```

#### Output

```
name1.txt
0 1 2 3

name2.txt
0 4 5 6

name3.txt
0 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're looping over all data for each file. Instead, you want to get only the data associated with that file. To do this, you can use `enumerate()` to get a list index. Also, you do not need `f.writelines()` because you're only writing one line. Instead, use `f.write()`. Here's the code you're looking for:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
files = ['f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt']

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write('0 ' + str(data[i]).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(',', ''))
```